# SQL check value from another table

Tags: t-sql

I've got multiple tables
I made my query like this :

```
SELECT a.creation, b.caseno, c.instanceno
FROM TableB b
JOIN TableA a
ON a.caseno = b.caseno
JOIN TableC c
ON c.caseno = b.caseno
WHERE a.creation BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
```

I've got TableD who contains the following column

```
| InstanceNo | Position | Creation | TaskNo |
```

The idea is to add a new colum (result) on my query.
If instance from c.instanceno exist on tableD and taskno is 30 or 20, in that case i would like the d.creation but for the max(position).
If not the value null is enough for the column result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.creation, b.caseno, c.instanceno, d.creation
FROM TableB b
JOIN TableA a
ON a.caseno = b.caseno
JOIN TableC c
ON c.caseno = b.caseno
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(position) position, instanceno, creation, taskno FROM TableD GROUP BY instanceno, creation, taskno) d
ON d.instanceno = c.instanceno
AND d.taskno in (20,30)
WHERE a.creation BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
```